# SML datatypes struggle

Tags: parsing, grammar, sml

I have the following grammar that I need to translate into SML datatypes:

```
Integer ranges over SML integer constants.
Boolean ::= 'true' | 'false'
Operator ::= 'ADD' | 'IF' | 'LESS_THAN'
Arguments ::= ( ',' Expression ) *
Expression ::= 'INT' '(' Integer ')'
            | 'BOOL' '(' Boolean ')'
            | 'OPERATION' '(' Operator ',' '[' Expression ( ',' Expression ) * ']' ')'
```

I have managed the following:

```
datatype BOOL = true | false;
datatype OPERATOR = ADD | IF | LESS_THAN;
datatype INT = INT of int;
```

However I am struggling with datatypes `Arguments` and `Expression`. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

for ARGUMENTS, you can use a sequence of EXPRESSIONs, so something like a list of EXPRESSION would work fine (the parentheses need to be parsed, but you don't need to store them in your type, since they are always there).

for EXPRESSION, you need to combine the approach you've used in OPERATOR (where you have alternatives) with what you've done in INT (where you have `of ...`).  in otherwords it's going to be of the form `A of B | C of D | ...`.

also, you don't really need `INT of int` - you could just use an simple `int` (ie an integer) for INT - and i suspect ML has a boolean type that could use instead of defining a datatype for BOOL (in other words, you probably don't need to define a datatype at all for either of those - just use what is already present in the language).

ps it's also normal to add the "homework" tag for homework.

[edit for OPERATOR you have multiple types, but that's ok - just stick them in a tuple, like `(A,B)` whose type is written `a * b`.  for the sequence of expressions, use a list, like for ARGUMENTS.]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I am struggling with | OPERATION (i.e. I don't quite get how can I describe OPERATION as (OPERATOR, followed recursively by EXPRESSION) :S just started to learn SML and i find it quite tricky.

Comment: i added some more.  if you search around for "sml datatype" you can find a pile of examples.  it's very logical, simple and consistent. and don't worry about things like recursion; stick multiple values (of the same type) in lists (and multiple values of different types in tuples).